# Include only recents custom posts in WP rss feed

Tags: custom-post-types, rss, feed

How to disable `lastBuildDate` for rss feed and include only the posts created recently (ex. 3 days before now)?

If there is no post, let the feed be empty. I wants to show only recent posts in rss feed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. Did you try anything? If so, then please edit the question and add the CODE you've tried so far.

Comment: I did not write any code so far. Is there any wp function that do the rss post query in rss feed?

Answer (score 1):

### Removing `lastBuildDate`:

`lastBuildDate` should not be removed from the rss feed, it may cause [rss feed validation error/warning](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/SlashDate.html).

However, it's possible to filter the date using [`get_lastpostmodified`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_lastpostmodified/) filter hook.

### Filtering feed content listing:

The rules for filtering `feed` content listing is the same as the rules for filtering any content listing in WordPress, the only difference is that you'll have to use the [WP_Query::is_feed](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_feed/) check.

So in most cases, you'll have to use [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) accompanied by [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action hook and then use the CODE in a custom plugin or in the theme's `functions.php` file.

Also, to filter the date, you may use the [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).

### Example CODE:

The CODE below lists only the posts from ***3 days before now*** in the feed and gives an option to modify the value of `lastBuildDate` (as you've asked in the question).

```
function wpse334869_lastBuildDate( $lastpostmodified ) {
    // if you need, modify the $lastpostmodified here, before returning it
    return $lastpostmodified;   
}

function wpse334869_filter_feed( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_feed() ) {
        add_filter( 'get_lastpostmodified', 'wpse334869_lastBuildDate');
        $query->set( 'date_query', array(
            array(
                'after' => '3 days ago'
            )
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse334869_filter_feed' );
```

> **Note:** This is just a sample concept CODE, so make sure you test it before using it on a live site.

Further Reading:

1. [Customizing Feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds).
2. [Acceptable Date Strings](https://php.net/strtotime).